# GLPaint OpenGL ES 2 Undo

Tags: ios, iphone, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Anyone have any quick thoughts on getting this undo functionality over to ES 2.
https://github.com/larsxschneider/Undo-in-OpenGL-ES

I think the issues is below, but I don't know enough about OpenGL ES in general to know what needs to change. This is from PaintView.m Line 267

```
// Render remaining vbos
for (NSData *vbo in self.vertexBuffers)
{
    NSUInteger count = vbo.length / (sizeof(GL_FLOAT) * 2);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vbo.bytes);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, count);
}

// Display the buffer
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
```

And/Or the problem could deal with the way OpenGl is set up in this method

```
- (BOOL)createFramebuffer
```

Any help would be nice, I'm still trying different things,

Here is my attempt, as you can see it hangs a bit and it doesn't do what it should.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0pG5vRVzBTzUTZPYWNoenhkcWs/edit?usp=sharing

And for reference, the original is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html

Thanks big,

austin

Comment: A question to guide your study: what happens when the user touches the screen? Follow the chain of events from there and you'll get an idea of how the app adds "paint" to the picture. To support undo/redo you'll need a plan for tracking that action so you can remove or replicate it. (Don't forget iOS has an [undo architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/UndoArchitecture/UndoArchitecture.html) you can leverage for help with this.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but its more of a Open GL ES question. understand the undo, its just when I attempt to "paint" the scene after removing some of the VBOs (an undo) it doesn't "paint" as I would expect because Im using the same method(s) which are used to "paint" in the first place... A simple way to ask it is... "How do I render an Array of VBO objects? (in OpenGL ES v2)", maybe ill just ask that as a separate question. thanks,